# Need functionality with all post list available at edit.php

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, wp-admin

I have solved the main query:

For WordPress dashboard, I needed the list of all posts related to all post types in:

```
edit.php?post_type=product
```

Using the concept of:

```
edit.php?post_type=product&showall=true
```

With function in backend `function.php`

```
function show_all_posttypes( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
         return;
    }

    if( isset( $_GET, $_GET['showall'] ) && true == $_GET['showall'] ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('product', 'second_type_product', 'third_type_product') );
    }   
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_all_posttypes' );
```

And after that my all posts related to three post types: product, second_type_product, third_type_product is listing very well on URL:

> edit.php?post_type=product&showall=true

But when I am using its feature to filter on edit.php page with all listed posts then is saying:

> Invalid post type

I want to achieve every feature support with my list related to multiple post types list on url based on one post type.

Thanks for support!

Comment: Did you try adding a check for `$query->is_main_query()`?

Comment: I think it is one of the thing I need to solve this issue, but not the solution.

Comment: @brianjohnhanna Just test the code without that check, it works.

Answer (score 1):

`Invalid Post Type` might be shown,whenever you have a mistake(type or etc..) in `'product', 'second_type_product', 'third_type_product'`  . Ensure that you have correct words there.

Comment: I used the code above and a fresh install of wordpress, and it worked just fine.  The only issue was that a couple warnings popped up because there are some pieces of edit.php that do not work with an array of post types, tries to print out the array as a string.  Otherwise, @tazo's solution should be correct.

Comment: @tazo-todua Just test the code without wrong types included, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would debug it like following:

- Check where the error is being thrown - This almost for certain in the wp-admin/edit.php file - debug the $post_type variable there
- Try to set the post type variable in your pre_get_posts query correctly

Furthermore, it would be nice if you could share some code with which I can test your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. From the error message and the URL parameters, I can guess there is not CPT `product` in your install, it would work if you replace use any post types registered (`post`, `page`, ...) or added a CPT `product` (by installing WooCommerce for example).

And by the way, I believe you are replacing all posts listing pages on the dashboard with the same page that lists `product`, `second_type_product` and `third_type_product`. Are you sure this is what you want?